# Using ${\rm Lip}1$ to show that $C[0,1]$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, separable-spaces

I am studying for my PhD qualifying exams by going through the problems in Carothers, and I have come across this problem.

For each $n$, show that $$\{ f \in {\rm Lip}1 : \rVert f \lVert_{{\rm Lip}1} \leq n \}$$ is a compact subset of $C[0,1]$. Use this to give another proof that $C[0,1]$ is separable.

Here, ${\rm Lip}1 = \cup_{K=1}^{\infty} {\rm Lip}_K1$ where ${\rm Lip}_K1$ are the Lipschitz functions with Lipschitz constant $K$ of order 1.

I have proven these sets are compact but don't know how that helps. I know that ${\rm Lip}1$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ so I only need to show that ${\rm Lip}1$ is countable. I was thinking since ${\rm Lip}1$ is the countable union of the sets that I showed were compact, if I could show those compact sets themselves were countable I would be done, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: No, $\operatorname{Lip}$ is not countable (being a nontrivial $\mathbb{R}$-vector space).

Comment: There are a continuum of lipschitz functions of any lipschitz constant. You can see this by making a family of ‘tent’ functions with graph \_^\_ Where the spike is at a real number. You can Make the spike short so that the lipschitz constant is small and then move the spike over some open subset of [0,1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any compact set in  a metric space is separable. Hence Lip1 is separable and so is its closure.

If $D_n$ is a coutable dense set in $\{f\in Lip1:\|f\|_{Lip1} \leq n\}$ then $\cup_n D_n$ is a  countable dense set in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that compact sets in metric spaces are separable.